# How To Parse Json File back Into Localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, import, local-storage

I have an html table I use offline with localstorage (no server) just html/css/js(bootstrap,jquery). I have successfully been able to export the localstorage to a json file. I would like to be able to import this file and repopulate the data on the table with this json file.

I have been able to accomplish this through the console with

**EXPORT**

```
copy(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(localStorage)));
```

However like I stated I would like to be able to accomplish this through JavaScript on the frontend.

I load the file and able to parse it perfectly to console, just having trouble getting it back into localstorage.

```
     document.querySelector('.sbm').addEventListener('click', () => {

            let fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function () {
                let parsedJSON = JSON.parse(fileReader.result);
                lssave(parsedJSON);                 
            }
            fileReader.readAsText(document.querySelector('.file').files[0]);
            
          }) 
          function lssave(json) {
          //   console.log(json)
          var data = json
          Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
          localStorage.setItem(k, data[k]);
          });

        }
```

However from here is where i am stuck, I puzzled at the moment so seeking assitance with i.e. how to parse jason back into localstorage, I am not on a server environment just running a index html with some css and js (bootstrap,jquery). Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
json example: this is how it looks raw when I save the file.

```
"{\"comments3\":\"HELLO 3<br>\",\"comments2\":\"hello 2<br>\",\"myitems\":\"\",\"comments\":\"hello1\",\"comments4\":\"HELLO 4<br>\"}"
```

json example: this is how it looks when I import it and print to console.

```
{"comments3":"HELLO 3","comments2":"hello 2","myitems":"","comments":"hello1","comments4":"HELLO 4<br>"}
```

Comment: What about using `lssave` on the unparsed JSON?

Comment: Because each object property needs to be saved separately. It has to be parsed so it can be iterated over.

Comment: What is the basic structure of the json? Often it's just as easy to store the whole object/array in one storage key

Comment: @charlietfl i added the json example in the question. Also went ahead and threw codepen examples if you care to take a look at, one is the export only version and the other is the import only version; export [link](https://codepen.io/noobish619/pen/PopMXVG) | Import [link](https://codepen.io/noobish619/pen/PopMVXQ) - did this so a potential individual can easily replicate where I am stuck at which is trying to import the json file I exported back into the localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

On each `forEach` iteration `JSON.stringify` the data:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
  localStorage.setItem(k, JSON.stringify(data[k]));
});
```

You can also use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) which is a little easier to read:

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(function ([key, value]) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
});
```

I've tested this code and it works.

JS

```
function lssave(data) { 
  Object.entries(data).forEach(function([key, value]) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  });
};

document.querySelector('input').on('change', (event) => {
  let fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    let parsedJSON = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
    lssave(parsedJSON);
  }

  fileReader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
```

Comment: gets a uncaught DOMException: The quota has been exceeded. not in private mode either.

Comment: Try clearing out your localStorage for your site through the dev tools, restarting the browser, and rechecking. It worked fine for me earlier.

Comment: yeah that cleared up the error however my data from the json is still not being parsed back into localstorage, not sure why not though.

Comment: You should add an example of your JSON to your question.

Comment: added the json example edit to the question. Also went ahead and threw up 2 codepen examples if you care to take a look at, one is the export and the other is the import. export [link](https://codepen.io/noobish619/pen/PopMXVG) | Import [link](https://codepen.io/noobish619/pen/PopMVXQ) - so you can export the json and try to import it. I am at a standstill.

Comment: @JustNoobish619, I've updated my answer with a working example.

Comment: I don't know what to say, its just aint working on my end. Tried on both firefox and Chrome. I have also implemented your working code to the copepen example and it doesn't work their either if you care to take a peek. Here's the link export  [link](https://codepen.io/noobish619/pen/PopMXVG) | import [;ink](https://codepen.io/noobish619/pen/PopMVXQ)

Comment: Just a tip: `const json = await new Response(file).json()` - Don't need the fileReader

Comment: @Endless can you show an example? Not sure how To implement this my situation.

Comment: in Andy's example you could just do `new Response(event.target.files[0]).json().then(lssave)`